How do I calculate the great circle distance between two points on Earth in OpenLayers?
OpenLayers has sphere.getDistance function, but the results vary from what I get on Google Earth by a few miles.  I assume this is due to the ellipsoid shape of the Earth instead of being a perfect sphere, but I don't know how to account for that.
I wrote a JSFiddle that calculates the distance from 40N, 75W (New York area) to 25N, 80W (Miami area) which should be 932.98 nautical miles, but I'm getting 935.08 using OpenLayers sphere.getDistance.    The error is less significant with an East/West (New York to Los Angeles) route than a North/South route.
    const distanceInMeters = ol.sphere.getDistance(
    [latLon1[1], latLon1[0]],
    [latLon2[1], latLon2[0]],
    )

    const metersPerNm = 1852
    const distanceInNM = distanceInMeters / metersPerNm

    var distanceDiv = document.getElementById("calculatedDistance")
    distanceDiv.innerText = distanceInNM.toFixed(2) + " nm"

https://jsfiddle.net/7n3kLamr/2/
How can I correct this?
Most of the similar issues I've found online use the old OpenLayers versions with a sphere.haversineDistance function, but that does not exist in current OL versions.
OmniCalculator.com has some info about the calculations necessary for a more accurate distance, but I'm hoping there is already a library out there that does this.
https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/great-circle

OpenLayers 2 had an ellipsoidal method.  You could extract the code used from https://github.com/openlayers/ol2/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Util.js#L756-L795
